# check function return value without execute it again

Tags: php, function, return

how to get function return value without execute it again?

i used this but this execute function again

**my function:**

```
function article()
{
    if($_GET['action'] == "article" && !empty($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        $article = array();
        $selectArticle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'");
        $rowArticle = mysql_fetch_array($selectArticle);

        $id = $rowArticle['id'];
        $title = stripcslashes($rowArticle['title']);
        $category = stripcslashes($rowArticle['category']);
        $image = stripcslashes($rowArticle['image']);
        $description = stripcslashes($rowArticle['description']);
        $full_description = stripcslashes($rowArticle['full_description']);
        $keywords = stripcslashes($rowArticle['keywords']);
        $url = "/article/" . $rowArticle['id'] . "/" . str_replace(" ","-",stripcslashes($rowArticle['title']));
        $article = array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'category' => $category, 'image' => $image, 'description' => $description, 'full_description' => $full_description, 'keywords' => $keywords, 'url' => $url);
        mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET visits=visits+1 WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    return $article;
}
```

**how to check it**

```
if (article() != null)
{
    $article = article();
    return $article['title'];
}
```

Comment: you may also store article() to a variable, and use the variable $article instead of article()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
if (null !== ($article = article())) {
    return $article['title'];
}
```

This does a 'simultaneous' assignment AND comparison. 
First, this part is evaluated: `($article = article())`. It yields a `null` value or an `array` which is stored in `$article`.
Its result (`null` or `array`) is then evaluated by the if structure: `if (null !== $article)` and normal flow resumes.

Comment: this portion don't run function again? -> ($article = article())

Comment: i have a update mysql query in article() function and this execute it again and update query runs twice. the article function executed before  i don't want to execute it again

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by 'execute it again'. The code I posted runs the `article()` function once.

Comment: i called article() before and ($article = article()) call it again

Comment: So in your original example the `article()` function ran three times? That means there is more code than you have posted. You should post your complete code.

Comment: yes it is but i need return value & i dont want call the function again. can i do it by another function or variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32063/discussion-between-dennis-haarbrink-and-mohammad-masoudian)

Answer (score 1):

like so

```
$article_var = article();

if ($article_var!=null)
{
      //do stuff
      //return $article['title'] // etc
}
```

Comment: the function executed before i don't want to execute it again

Answer (score 0):

Modify the check a little bit.

```
$article = article();
return $article != null ? $article['title'] : null;
```